# JSON for loop through array shows only last value

Tags: php, json, axios

I am trying mas a simple HTTP post  request using AXIOS.Its like an Ajax request to retrieve the data .  Here is the HTML. Its sends a post request to the getData.php.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>axios - post example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body class="container">
<h1>Axios.post</h1>

<form role="form" class="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="data">Output</label>
        <textarea id="data" class="form-control container" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="post" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">POST</button>
</form>

<!--<div id="output" class=""></div>-->

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function () {

        document.getElementById('post').onclick = function () {
            var output = document.getElementById('data');
            axios.post('getData.php')
                .then(function (res) {


                   // console.log(res.data);
                    output.className = 'container';
                        for (i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
                        output.innerHTML = res.data[i].id + "\n" + res.data[i].name;

                    }

                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    output.className = 'container text-danger';
                    output.innerHTML = err.message;
                });
        };
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

In the  getData.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,"db_test");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$resultArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultArray[] = $row;

    }

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
    return;

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

But when i am trying to for loop through the array it returns only the last row.It fetches the data from the table and create an array. Whats wrong with the for loop ?

Comment: BAD, not concatenating  `output.innerHTML =` GOOD is concatenating `output.innerHTML +=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output.innerHTML = res.data[i].id + "\n" + res.data[i].name;`

will just replace everything previously added.

`output.innerHTML += res.data[i].id + "\n" + res.data[i].name;`

would fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because your overwriting  `output.innerHTML` In for loop so `last value` only exists .

use `appendChild()`

```
output.appendChild(res.data[i].id + "\n" + res.data[i].name);
```